# Shapefile quadtree in shapelib

Tags: c, shapefile, quadtree

In [shapelib](http://shapelib.maptools.org), I've noted that quite amount of code is meant to handle Shapefile quadtree. For instance, the tool shptreedump (in shapelib source code).

> warmerda@gdal[207]% shptreedump -maxdepth 6 eg_data/polygon.shp (
>   SHPTreeNode   Min = (471127.19,4751545.00)   Max =
>   (489292.31,4765610.50)   Shapes(0):    ( SHPTreeNode
>       Min = (471127.19,4751545.00)
>       Max = (481118.01,4765610.50)
>       Shapes(0): 
>       ( SHPTreeNode
>         Min = (471127.19,4751545.00)
>         Max = (481118.01,4759281.03)
>         Shapes(0): 
>         ( SHPTreeNode
>           Min = (471127.19,4751545.00)
>           Max = (476622.14,4759281.03)
>           Shapes(0): 
>           ( SHPTreeNode
>             Min = (471127.19,4751545.00)
>             Max = (476622.14,4755799.81)
>             Shapes(0): 
>             ( SHPTreeNode
>               Min = (471127.19,4751545.00)
>               Max = (474149.41,4755799.81)
>               Shapes(6): 395 397 402 404 405 422 
>             )
>             ( SHPTreeNode
>               Min = (473599.92,4751545.00)
>               Max = (476622.14,4755799.81)
>               Shapes(10): 392 394 403 413 414 417 426 433 434 447 
>             )
>           ) ...

I think I've been quite familiar with shapefile format after reading the [ESRI Shapefile Technical Description](http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf%E2%80%8E). But I can't see any internal tree structure itself. So my question is, what is the shapefile quadtree for? And if possible, with explanation of shapefile quadtree implementation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the end of your quoted text, right where you stopped, lots of closing parenthesis...good old Lisp style encoding:

(R (st1 (st21 () () () ()) () () ()) (st2) (st3) (st4))

R stands for the root of the tree, then you have four subtrees in () plus the actual data st1, I denoted the 4 subtrees by st1...st4. st21 stands for the first subtree on the second level. The subtrees could be labeled, or if any of them empty denoted by (). It is easy to parse and print.

Comment: +1 Thank you, It helps though it does not directly address my question.

Comment: The lisp notation explains the tree structure. The quadtree is a spatial decomposition of the 2d space into regions identified by 2 opposite corners so you can find a point in it fast. It is a generalisation of the binary tree which is for searching for 'numbers' in 1d space. Wikipedia would be a good start for implementation details.